# How to place Markers on a Map in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-react

I am trying to place Markers by mapping through locations that I have in my database.

I thought that just placing the `Marker` inside of where I am mapping the data and then calling that variable inside of the return in between the `Map`  would do it, but it didn't work.

I know it's properly converting the cities because when I console log it the coordinates show up as intended. Not sure what it is I am doing wrong.

Does anyone have any insights into why this is happening? Like, I'll take any info on this that can help.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Map,Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from "google-maps-react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {getVacations} from "./redux";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

class GoogleMaps extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
       componentDidMount = () => {
           this.props.getVacations();
       }

       render() {

        console.log(this.props);
         const mappedCoordinates = this.props.vacations.map(coordinate => {
             Geocode.fromAddress(coordinate.location).then(
                 response => {
                     const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                     console.log(lat, lng);
                     <Marker position={{lat: lat, lng: lng}}/>
                 })
         })
         return (
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={4}>
                {mappedCoordinates}
             </Map>
            </div>
        )
       }
    }

    const connectVaca = connect(state => ({vacations: state}), {getVacations})(GoogleMaps);


export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: "<API KEY GOES HERE>"
})(connectVaca)
```